# C Pointers to Swift Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, swift3

I'm trying to convert a piece of C code to Swift 3 both using pointers.
Here is relevant part in C code.

```
Float32 sampleArray[256] = { // Array is 256 Float values
0.00000, 0.00000, -0.00060, 0.00000, -0.00237, 0.00000, -0.00528 etc.etc}


float *p1, *p2, temp;
long i, bitm, j;

for (i = 2; i < 128-2; i += 2) {

    for (bitm = 2, j = 0; bitm < 256; bitm <<= 1) {
        if (i & bitm){j++;}
        j <<= 1;
    }

    if (i < j ) {
        p1 = sampleArray+i;
        p2 = sampleArray+j;
        temp = *p1;
        *(p1++) = *p2;    //Stuck from this point onwards
        *(p2++) = temp;
        temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = temp;
    }
}//eo for
```

And here is my swift attempt. Obviously using the same type of array but in swift

```
var bitm:CLong
var j:CLong
var temp:Float
var p1:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
var p2:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>

for i in stride(from: 2, to: 128-2, by: 2){
    j = 0
    bitm = 2;
    while bitm < 256 {
        if (i & bitm != 0){ j = j + 1}
        j = j<<1
        bitm<<=1
    }

    if (i < j){
        p1 = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: sampleArray)+i
        p2 = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: sampleArray)+j
        temp = p1.pointee
        /* looks ok up to this point*/

    }

}//eo stride
```

As you can tell i have got as far as

```
*(p1++) = *p2;
```

I thought this might be a case of shifting the pointers using

```
p1.advanced(by: 1)
```

any help with the last four lines would be appreciated i notice that

```
p2.pointee = somevalue
```

describes the points in the array that need working on. And if i replace everything as

```
 sampleArray[j] = sampleArray[i]
```

gets me closer to work in few lines of code. But i would like to keep it as pointers. So i can get my head round how they works in swift.Thank you..

for clarity here is the sampleArray

```
    var sampleArray:[Float] = [
        0.00000, 0.00000, -0.00060, 0.00000, -0.00237, 0.00000, -0.00528, 0.00000, -0.00931, 0.00000, -0.01440, 0.00000, -0.02052, 0.00000, -0.02762, 0.00000, -0.03566, 0.00000, -0.04460, 0.00000, -0.05443, 0.00000, -0.06502, 0.00000, -0.07634, 0.00000, -0.08836, 0.00000, -0.10101, 0.00000, -0.11424, 0.00000, -0.12799, 0.00000, -0.14238, 0.00000, -0.15703, 0.00000, -0.17203, 0.00000, -0.18733, 0.00000, -0.20286, 0.00000, -0.21858, 0.00000, -0.23470, 0.00000, -0.25063, 0.00000, -0.26657, 0.00000, -0.28247, 0.00000, -0.29827, 0.00000, -0.31392, 0.00000, -0.32979, 0.00000, -0.34501, 0.00000, -0.35993, 0.00000, -0.37450, 0.00000, -0.38868, 0.00000, -0.40242, 0.00000, -0.41569, 0.00000, -0.42904, 0.00000, -0.44126, 0.00000, -0.45289, 0.00000, -0.46390, 0.00000, -0.47426, 0.00000, -0.48394, 0.00000, -0.49365, 0.00000, -0.50193, 0.00000, -0.50945, 0.00000, -0.51621, 0.00000, -0.52219, 0.00000, -0.52738, 0.00000, -0.53176, 0.00000, -0.53621, 0.00000, -0.53900, 0.00000, -0.54096, 0.00000, -0.54212, 0.00000, -0.54246, 0.00000, -0.54199, 0.00000, -0.54169, 0.00000, -0.53965, 0.00000, -0.53684, 0.00000, -0.53327, 0.00000, -0.52895, 0.00000, -0.52392, 0.00000, -0.51918, 0.00000, -0.51276, 0.00000, -0.50570, 0.00000, -0.49800, 0.00000, -0.48971, 0.00000, -0.48084, 0.00000, -0.47144, 0.00000, -0.46251, 0.00000, -0.45212, 0.00000, -0.44129, 0.00000, -0.43005, 0.00000, -0.41844, 0.00000, -0.40650, 0.00000, -0.39520, 0.00000, -0.38269, 0.00000, -0.36996, 0.00000, -0.35704, 0.00000, -0.34396, 0.00000, -0.33078, 0.00000, -0.31752, 0.00000, -0.30506, 0.00000, -0.29174, 0.00000, -0.27845, 0.00000, -0.26523, 0.00000, -0.25210, 0.00000, -0.23910, 0.00000, -0.22698, 0.00000, -0.21432, 0.00000, -0.20187, 0.00000, -0.18967, 0.00000, -0.17775, 0.00000, -0.16612, 0.00000, -0.15538, 0.00000, -0.14439, 0.00000, -0.13376, 0.00000, -0.12350, 0.00000, -0.11364, 0.00000, -0.10418, 0.00000, -0.09514, 0.00000, -0.08693, 0.00000, -0.07873, 0.00000, -0.07097, 0.00000, -0.06366, 0.00000, -0.05679, 0.00000, -0.05038, 0.00000, -0.04467, 0.00000, -0.03911, 0.00000, -0.03400, 0.00000, -0.02931, 0.00000, -0.02504, 0.00000, -0.02118, 0.00000, -0.01772, 0.00000, -0.01477, 0.00000, -0.01203, 0.00000, -0.00964, 0.00000, -0.00758, 0.00000, -0.00583, 0.00000, -0.00437, 0.00000, -0.00322, 0.00000, -0.00225, 0.00000, -0.00149, 0.00000, -0.00093, 0.00000, -0.00052, 0.00000, -0.00026, 0.00000, -0.00011, 0.00000, -0.00003, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000,]
```

And this is what the output should be according to the c code

```
0.0000, 0.0000, -0.4980, 0.0000, -0.3745, 0.0000, -0.1235, 0.0000, -0.1280, 0.0000, -0.3175, 0.0000, -0.5318, 0.0000, -0.0177, 0.0000, -0.0357, 0.0000, -0.4184, 0.0000, -0.4743, 0.0000, -0.0568, 0.0000, -0.2506, 0.0000, -0.2143, 0.0000, -0.5396, 0.0000, -0.0022, 0.0000, -0.0093, 0.0000, -0.4625, 0.0000, -0.4290, 0.0000, -0.0869, 0.0000, -0.1873, 0.0000, -0.2652, 0.0000, -0.5421, 0.0000, -0.0076, 0.0000, -0.0763, 0.0000, -0.3700, 0.0000, -0.5094, 0.0000, -0.0340, 0.0000, -0.3139, 0.0000, -0.1661, 0.0000, -0.5239, 0.0000, -0.0003, 0.0000, -0.0024, 0.0000, -0.4808, 0.0000, -0.4024, 0.0000, -0.1042, 0.0000, -0.1570, 0.0000, -0.2917, 0.0000, -0.5390, 0.0000, -0.0120, 0.0000, -0.0544, 0.0000, -0.3952, 0.0000, -0.4937, 0.0000, -0.0447, 0.0000, -0.2825, 0.0000, -0.1897, 0.0000, -0.5333, 0.0000, -0.0009, 0.0000, -0.0205, 0.0000, -0.4413, 0.0000, -0.4529, 0.0000, -0.0710, 0.0000, -0.2186, 0.0000, -0.2391, 0.0000, -0.5420, 0.0000, -0.0044, 0.0000, -0.1010, 0.0000, -0.3440, 0.0000, -0.5222, 0.0000, -0.0250, 0.0000, -0.3450, 0.0000, -0.1444, 0.0000, -0.5128, 0.0000, -0.5057, 0.0000, -0.0006, 0.0000, -0.4897, 0.0000, -0.3887, 0.0000, -0.4714, 0.0000, -0.1424, 0.0000, -0.4521, 0.0000, -0.5362, 0.0000, -0.4301, 0.0000, -0.0446, 0.0000, -0.4065, 0.0000, -0.4839, 0.0000, -0.3827, 0.0000, -0.2666, 0.0000, -0.3570, 0.0000, -0.5368, 0.0000, -0.3308, 0.0000, -0.0144, 0.0000, -0.3051, 0.0000, -0.4413, 0.0000, -0.2785, 0.0000, -0.2029, 0.0000, -0.2521, 0.0000, -0.5425, 0.0000, -0.2270, 0.0000, -0.0884, 0.0000, -0.2019, 0.0000, -0.5162, 0.0000, -0.1777, 0.0000, -0.3298, 0.0000, -0.1554, 0.0000, -0.5192, 0.0000, -0.1338, 0.0000, -0.0053, 0.0000, -0.1136, 0.0000, -0.4157, 0.0000, -0.0951, 0.0000, -0.1720, 0.0000, -0.0787, 0.0000, -0.5410, 0.0000, -0.0637, 0.0000, -0.0650, 0.0000, -0.0504, 0.0000, -0.5019, 0.0000, -0.0391, 0.0000, -0.2983, 0.0000, -0.0293, 0.0000, -0.5290, 0.0000, -0.0212, 0.0000, -0.0276, 0.0000, -0.0148, 0.0000, -0.4639, 0.0000, -0.0096, 0.0000, -0.2347, 0.0000, -0.0058, 0.0000, -0.5417, 0.0000, -0.0032, 0.0000, -0.1142, 0.0000, -0.0015, 0.0000, -0.5274, 0.0000, -0.0005, 0.0000, -0.3599, 0.0000, -0.0001, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000,
```

Answer (score 2):

One very bad thing in your code:

```
UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: sampleArray)
```

Check the [Pointer part](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23) of the [Using book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216)

> #### Constant Pointers
>
> ...
>
> The pointer passed to the function is guaranteed to be valid only for
>   the duration of the function call. Don’t try to persist the pointer
>   and access it after the function has returned.

So, the pointer passed to `UnsafeMutablePointer.init(mutating:)` may not be valid after the call of the initializer. Of course the returned pointer may not be valid neither.

You need to declare your `sampleArray` as `var` and use `withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer(_:)`, if you want to use a pointer to Swift Array which is guaranteed to be valid inside the closure:

```
sampleArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {bufferPointer in
    let sampleArrayPointer = bufferPointer.baseAddress!
    for i in stride(from: 2, to: 128-2, by: 2) {
        var j: CLong = 0
        var bitm: CLong = 2
        while bitm < 256 {
            if i & bitm != 0 { j += 1 }
            j <<= 1
            bitm <<= 1
        }

        if i < j {
            // p1 = sampleArray+i;
            var p1 = sampleArrayPointer + i
            // p2 = sampleArray+j;
            var p2 = sampleArrayPointer + j
            // temp = *p1;
            var temp = p1.pointee
            // *(p1++) = *p2;
            p1.pointee = p2.pointee
            p1 += 1
            // *(p2++) = temp;
            p2.pointee = temp
            p2 += 1
            // temp = *p1;
            temp = p1.pointee
            // *p1 = *p2;
            p1.pointee = p2.pointee
            // *p2 = temp;
            p2.pointee = temp
        }
    }//eo stride}
}
```

But as suggested in Codo's answer, you have no need to use pointers in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`p1++` in C corresponds to

`p1.successor()` or  `p1.advanced(by: 1)` in Swift

```
*(p1++)
```

in C means get the value from the pointer which corresponds to

```
p1.successor().pointee
```

in Swift

So rest of the code will be like

```
 if (i < j){

        p1 = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: sampleArray)+i
        p2 = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: sampleArray)+j
        temp = p1.pointee
        /* looks ok up to this point*/

        p1.successor().pointee  = p2.pointee
        p2.successor().pointee = temp
        temp = p1.pointee
        p1.pointee = p2.pointee
        p2.pointee = temp
    }
```

Comment: i had never heard of successor your  code although great doesn't get exactly what i want as every other value should be zero. But it certainly gives me a fighting chance. I will report back thanks

Comment: I feel that `swap` function could be used there somehow

Comment: @Sulthan The OP just wanted to convert C pointer to Swift Pointer..If you would go and check the question history

Answer (score 1):

Your C code simply uses pointers to access array elements. There is no need to use pointers, neither in C nor in Swift. This style of C code might have been faster 30 years ago. But today it prevents the compiler from effectively using registers.

The good news is: we don't need pointers and can convert it to Swift easily. The code you're stuck at really just swaps the elements at i / j and at i + 1 / j + 1.

```
var sampleArray: [Float] = [
    0.00000, 0.00000, -0.00060, 0.00000, -0.00237, 0.00000, -0.00528, 0.00000, -0.00931, 0.00000, -0.01440, 0.00000, -0.02052, 0.00000, -0.02762, 0.00000, -0.03566, 0.00000, -0.04460, 0.00000, -0.05443, 0.00000, -0.06502, 0.00000, -0.07634, 0.00000, -0.08836, 0.00000, -0.10101, 0.00000, -0.11424, 0.00000, -0.12799, 0.00000, -0.14238, 0.00000, -0.15703, 0.00000, -0.17203, 0.00000, -0.18733, 0.00000, -0.20286, 0.00000, -0.21858, 0.00000, -0.23470, 0.00000, -0.25063, 0.00000, -0.26657, 0.00000, -0.28247, 0.00000, -0.29827, 0.00000, -0.31392, 0.00000, -0.32979, 0.00000, -0.34501, 0.00000, -0.35993, 0.00000, -0.37450, 0.00000, -0.38868, 0.00000, -0.40242, 0.00000, -0.41569, 0.00000, -0.42904, 0.00000, -0.44126, 0.00000, -0.45289, 0.00000, -0.46390, 0.00000, -0.47426, 0.00000, -0.48394, 0.00000, -0.49365, 0.00000, -0.50193, 0.00000, -0.50945, 0.00000, -0.51621, 0.00000, -0.52219, 0.00000, -0.52738, 0.00000, -0.53176, 0.00000, -0.53621, 0.00000, -0.53900, 0.00000, -0.54096, 0.00000, -0.54212, 0.00000, -0.54246, 0.00000, -0.54199, 0.00000, -0.54169, 0.00000, -0.53965, 0.00000, -0.53684, 0.00000, -0.53327, 0.00000, -0.52895, 0.00000, -0.52392, 0.00000, -0.51918, 0.00000, -0.51276, 0.00000, -0.50570, 0.00000, -0.49800, 0.00000, -0.48971, 0.00000, -0.48084, 0.00000, -0.47144, 0.00000, -0.46251, 0.00000, -0.45212, 0.00000, -0.44129, 0.00000, -0.43005, 0.00000, -0.41844, 0.00000, -0.40650, 0.00000, -0.39520, 0.00000, -0.38269, 0.00000, -0.36996, 0.00000, -0.35704, 0.00000, -0.34396, 0.00000, -0.33078, 0.00000, -0.31752, 0.00000, -0.30506, 0.00000, -0.29174, 0.00000, -0.27845, 0.00000, -0.26523, 0.00000, -0.25210, 0.00000, -0.23910, 0.00000, -0.22698, 0.00000, -0.21432, 0.00000, -0.20187, 0.00000, -0.18967, 0.00000, -0.17775, 0.00000, -0.16612, 0.00000, -0.15538, 0.00000, -0.14439, 0.00000, -0.13376, 0.00000, -0.12350, 0.00000, -0.11364, 0.00000, -0.10418, 0.00000, -0.09514, 0.00000, -0.08693, 0.00000, -0.07873, 0.00000, -0.07097, 0.00000, -0.06366, 0.00000, -0.05679, 0.00000, -0.05038, 0.00000, -0.04467, 0.00000, -0.03911, 0.00000, -0.03400, 0.00000, -0.02931, 0.00000, -0.02504, 0.00000, -0.02118, 0.00000, -0.01772, 0.00000, -0.01477, 0.00000, -0.01203, 0.00000, -0.00964, 0.00000, -0.00758, 0.00000, -0.00583, 0.00000, -0.00437, 0.00000, -0.00322, 0.00000, -0.00225, 0.00000, -0.00149, 0.00000, -0.00093, 0.00000, -0.00052, 0.00000, -0.00026, 0.00000, -0.00011, 0.00000, -0.00003, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000
]

var i = 2
while i < 256 - 2 {

    var bitm = 2
    var j = 0

    while bitm < 256 {
        if (i & bitm) != 0 {
            j += 1
        }
        j <<= 1
        bitm <<= 1
    }

    if i < j {
        swap(&sampleArray[i], &sampleArray[j])
        swap(&sampleArray[i + 1], &sampleArray[j + 1])
    }

    i += 2
}
```

Comment: it's preferable to use `swap(_:_:)`

Comment: I have added the input array and what i believe the output should be to the original post. I'm not sure they are matching yet.

Comment: I've fixed the compile errors and used swap (as proposed by @AlexanderMomchliov). I've only compared the first about 30 values and they seem to match.

Comment: @oldman: The output of my code differs from the one you show in your questions. But so does the output of your C code, which I also run. Interestingly, the output of my Swift code seems to match the output of the C code.

Comment: The reference output shown may be generated with `for (i = 2; i < 256-2; i += 2) {`, not `128-2`. Try changing your `128 - 2` to `256 - 2`.

Comment: @OOPer: Yes, indeed. With this change it produces the expected result.

Comment: The expected output for the code in C was wrong on my part. I have corrected the original